# Making a web page with ruby without rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I´m looking for a way to do simple ruby code without rails. I´m coming from PHP world, and sometimes, I just build a page with a Mysql connection, run a query and show result in a simple table (for example, a simple log or report).
Example:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
   echo "<p> $data[name] - $data[age] </p>";
}
?>
```

This is just a simple example, but reflects what I need to do with ruby. I don´t want all rails framework to just do something like this. How can I achieve this with simple ruby code?

Comment: Please cure my and anyone else's OCD; you forgot a double-quote after localhost.

Comment: @Zirak, you can edit someone else's question to fix things like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, Ruby is not like php. No droping files into public_html and expecting everything to work.

Never the less, it is possible to do it that way, kinda. So we are using Mysql adapter with no ORM as php does by default.

Before you start, you will need mysql adapter, so install it with:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Than write something like:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mysql2"

client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "",
  :database => "mydb"
)
records = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")

records.each {|r| p "<p>#{r['name']} - #{r['age']}</p>"}
```

Now run it in console with

```
ruby name_of_the _file.rb
```

This will output records in console. If you want browser output, you will have to write a small server:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'socket'
require 'mysql2'

webserver = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 6789)

client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "",
  :database => "mydb"
)

records = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")

while (session = webserver.accept)
   session.print "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
   request = session.gets
   records.each {|r| session.print "<p>#{r['name']} - #{r['age']}</p>"}
   session.close
 end
```

Now when you do `ruby application.rb`, server will be started on port 6789 and it will output required data. You can later reverse proxy on it and use it on port 80.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is [sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com). Or [camping](http://camping.rubyforge.org/).

However, the slightly longer answer is that Ruby doesn't follow the same execution model as PHP, so the development model of "stick some code in a file to be interpolated by the web server on every request" isn't as well supported.

Comment: "Without Rails" is not "without framework!"  Nevertheless, you can go a long way with just WEBrick: http://www.igvita.com/2007/02/13/building-dynamic-webrick-servers-in-ruby/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I know of is to use Ruby's CGI module, and run the script as CGI. Depending on your performance requirements and complexity of the page you want to generate, something like this might just do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'cgi'
require 'mysql'

con = Mysql.new("localhost","user","pass","mydb")
rs = con.query('select * from users')

cgi = CGI.new('html4')
cgi.out {
  cgi.html {
    cgi.body {
      rs.each_hash { |row| puts #{"row['name']} - #{row['age']}" }
    }
  }
}
```

You would want to consider the overhead of establishing connection to MySQL on each request, and for complex pages you will need a templating mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'activerecord'; require 'active_record'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql',
  :database => 'test',
  :user => 'user',
  :password => 'pass'
)

User.all.each do |u|
  puts "<p>#{u.name} - #{u.age}</p>"
end
```

Before running it you need to install activerecord:

```
gem install activerecord
```

Comment: @rizidoro Perhaps you should state what your constraints are, e.g. it sounds like you want to use Passenger, so you should mention that upfront. That helps people give answers closer to what you want.