# Ruby webpage shows only source code

Tags: ruby, cgi, html

I am trying to use Ruby to set up a home page. I currently have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

puts "Hello, Ruby!";
```

It is saved as testing.rb. I am able to host files onto my school's public server so I had it in my school's directory such as `school.ca/myname/public_html/testing.rb`.

This has worked for previous HTML, CSS, Perl, ASP, and PHP programs. Now I am trying to set up Ruby and I'm having trouble. All it displays on the URL is my source code from above.

I changed the file permissions to 644.

Comment: [This is relevant - Ruby isn't like PHP in that you can just drop it in and everything magically "works".](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5664553/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto, thanks for the link, really helpful!

Comment: *All it displays on the URL is my source code from above*.  Try giving your ruby file a `.cgi` extension.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Ruby as a CGI. I'd highly recommend reading about Sinatra, which is Ruby based, and is modern web-serving technology. It's much lighter-weight than Rails and the learning curve is subsequently much easier. And, it's very capable of handling complex tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Ruby aware web server. There is one solution that makes running Ruby almost as easy as running PHP: [Phusion Passenger](http://www.phusionpassenger.com/). It can be installed as an Apache or Nginx plugins, two very common web servers. However, in order to install these plugins you usually require root access to your server, which I assume you don't have.

An entirely different solution would be to use a cloud service provider such as [Heroku](http://www.phusionpassenger.com/). They offer free plans as long as you are ok with your app not running 24h/day. In order to use this service, you have to be familiar with `git` though, but then it is as easy as uploading your code through git to run your application.

As for building your first Ruby web application, you should check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). A simple hello world application would look as follows:

```
require "sinatra"

get "/" do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Sinatra is a Ruby Gem. You can install those libraries from the command line using a tool called `gem`:

```
gem install sinatra
```

Comment: I think I'll give a shot using the Sinatra method. However, Im a bit lost, where do I put the "require sinatra" code?

Comment: A Sinatra application can live in a single file. So you just put it at the top of your file. All five lines of the example above go into the same file.

Comment: @GreatShark, `require 'sinatra'` is not going to work unless you install the sinatra gem on your school's server, which I'm guessing they are not going to allow you to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I changed the file permissions to 644.

```
~/ruby_programs$ chmod 644 cgi.cgi
~/ruby_programs$ ls -al cgi.cgi
-rw-r--r--  1 7stud  staff  102 Nov 13 15:50 cgi.cgi
```

File permissions are displayed as follows:

1. First character is `-` or `d`: `-` means file, `d` means directory
2. Then there are three sets of three characters indicating permissions for `owner`, `group` and `other`:

> ```
> r = readable
> w = writable
> x = executable
> ```

644 produces the permissions:

```
 rw-r--r--
```

which are equivalent to:

```
owner: rw-  (read, write)
group: r--  (read only)
other: r--  (read only)
```

You don't have to know who is an `owner`, or who is part of a `group`, or who falls in the `other` category to recognize that no one has permission to execute the file.  You need to do this:

```
~/ruby_programs$ chmod a+x cgi.cgi   #=>all + x => give execute permissions to everyone
~/ruby_programs$ ls -al cgi.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 7stud  staff  102 Nov 13 15:50 cgi.cgi
```

Now the permissions are:

```
 owner: rwx
 group: r-x
 other: r-x
```

which means that now anyone can execute the file.

> All it displays on the URL is my source code from above.

If you haven't already done so, try giving your ruby file a `.cgi` extension.  Then use this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
puts "<html><body>Hello, Ruby!</body></html>"
```

Are you sure ruby is installed on your school's server?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is not a language that browsers can really interpret on their own without help - you need to either set up a server and have it print out an HTML webpage yourself, or use a framework that does so for you(i.e. Sinatra, Rails).

Comment: Browsers don't interpret PHP either.

Comment: This is true - those languages are pre-processed by the servers into a format the browser understands. Ruby isn't without some setup.